# How create Numeric literal token with roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to change InitializerExpressionSyntax node like below but an error occurred :Use Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.Syntax.Literal to create numeric literal token.  Parameter name :kind

```
public override syntaxnode VisitInitializerExpression (InitializerExpressionSyntax node )
{
    SeparatedSyntaxList<ExpressionSyntax> list =new SeparatedSyntaxList<ExpressionSyntax> ();
    foreach  (var item in RandomByteArray)
    {
        SyntaxToken t=SyntaxFactory.Token (default (SyntaxTriviaList),SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralToken, item.ToString (),item. ToString  (),(default (SyntaxTriviaList));//error is here
        list.Add (SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression  (SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression,t));
   }
    node=node. WithExpressions(list);
    return node;
}
```

Comment: What error occurred?

Comment: Error message : Use Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.Syntax.Literal to create numeric lateral token. Parameter name :kind

Comment: Also, if you're using the stuff from the Roslyn.* namespace, that means you're using _very_ old preview bits. Make sure you're using the current NuGet packages that have the name Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to create a token, within SyntaxFactory.Token; that is a SyntaxKind of a NumbericLiteralToken is not supported by the SyntaxFactory.Token function.

Instead, you'll need to use SyntaxFactory.Literal as requested by the API.

```
SyntaxFactory.Literal(default(SyntaxTriviaList), item.ToString(), item.ToString(), item.ToString(), default(SyntaxTriviaList));
```

Source; Rosalyn Reference Source

(SyntaxFactory.Token: http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Syntax/SyntaxFactory.cs,241)

(SyntaxFactory.Literal: http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Syntax/SyntaxFactory.cs,585)